# JTextField respond to key event AFTER the text is updated

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

Right now, when I add a `KeyListener` to a `JTextField`, I get an event, then the text updates. But what I need is for the `KeyListener` to respond *after* the text is updated. How would I go about doing that? Right now, I am setting a 10-millisecond delay to the response of the `KeyListener` in another thread, which is sufficient for the text to update and the user to not notice.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing has newer and better API's than AWT.

Instead you should be adding a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the `JTextfield`

A `DocumentEvent` is generated whenever the `Document` is updated.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Oh. I never actually bothered to realise that `KeyListener`s are AWT. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @AlexL., well Swing is built on top of AWT so you still have access to the old API, but the newer API's should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

So.... ummmm i know it's kind'a late X)

I kind'a gone around that by using the keyReleased method I noticed that the text gets updated before the key event it should give you something like this

```
JTextField jtf = new  JTextField();
jtf.addKeyaddKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // not here
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // not here 

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                //do the stuff here
            }
        });
```

note that I am not sure why it works but I would think that it has something to do with the typing speed or something, also I am not an expert but i wanted to help (that problem drove me crazy for a couple days) if i am saying any stupid stuff pleas let me know !